# Comment in a question is the answer

Tags: discussion

What should I do when I want to tag a comment to a question as giving the answer, even though the answer doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, but you could ask the person who posted the comment to instead post it as an answer, and then accept that.

Comment: go make your comment an answer then :P
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11406/how-to-describe-three-different-levels-of-sharing

Comment: Hahaha! Done. ;)